# What are the differences between preview render hair and rendered hair?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hair

Preview render is showing the hair like so:

[image: preview hair]
But, the rendered hair just completely destroys the beauty lower formation and instead smooths it out so it looks ugly like this

[image: ugly hair]

[image]

Comment: I've noticed numerous quirks with this as well. It would be great to get a definitive answer on how to match preview and render settings for hair.

Comment: @Sazerac I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The only differences as far as I can tell is the confusing steps variable in the render subcategory and the steps variable in the display category.

Once I make both of them two, the renders turn out exactly the same.